# Content Script not receiving messages from Background Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send messages from a background script to a content script in a chrome extension. But the content script never seems to get the message.

Here's my code:

**background.js**

So basically I want to send a message every second to the active tab's content script.

```
'use strict';

var timeSpentToday = 0;
var timeSpentTotal = 0;
var today = (new Date()).getDate(); // today's day, to track day changing
var mainTimerId; // 1s timer that will update timeSpentToday every second

mainTimerId = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

// function to be run every second
function updateTime() {

  ++timeSpentToday;
  ++timeSpentTotal;

  console.log(timeSpentToday);

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
      console.log(tabs)
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "sendTimeSpentToday", timeSpentToday: timeSpentToday}, function() {
        console.log('message sent')
      });  
    }
  });

  // check if we've changed day, and if it's the case, reset timeSpentToday to 0
  if ((new Date()).getDate() != today) {
    today = (new Date()).getDate();
    timeSpentToday = 0;
  }


}
```

**content.js**

```
console.log('Content script running.');
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request);
  if (request.method == 'sendTimeSpentToday') {

    var timeSpentToday = request.timeSpentToday;
    console.log(timeSpentToday);

    // update time label with hh:mm:ss format
    var hours = parseInt( timeSpentToday / 3600 ) % 24;
    var minutes = parseInt( timeSpentToday / 60 ) % 60;
    var seconds = timeSpentToday % 60;
    var hhmmss = (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours) + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) + ':' + (seconds  < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);
    document.getElementById('sf-timelabel').innerHTML = hhmmss;
  }
}
```

The content script is running, I see the 'Content script running' in my active tab's console. The background script is also running correctly, I see `timeSpentToday` being logged every second inside the extension's console, and the 'message sent' message too.

Note that I've also logged the queried tabs inside `background.js`. And I do get an array with one Tab object (the active tab):

```
Array[1]
  0: Object
    active: true
    audible: false
    height: 646
    highlighted: true
    id: 3635incognito: false
    index: 2
    mutedInfo: Object
    pinned: false
    selected: true
    status: "complete"
    width: 1332
    windowId: 36
    __proto__: Object
   length: 1
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

I just don't understand why sendMessage isn't sending the message to the correct content script, or why the content script isn't receiving the message.

Comment: The code looks okay. Maybe you are using Chrome 44-45 with a bug in `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` when no `frameId` is specified?

Comment: The code looks fine. Don't see why it wouldn't work. The only problem I can see from your code is missing closing parenthesis at `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {...});`

Comment: Could you temporarily add `"tabs"` permission so that your logging includes the URL?